# VBA Excel to JSON data when saved to text file adds extra double quotes - VBA Excel

Tags: json, excel, vba

I am using the library to convert my excel table data to json. when I print it on console or excel cell value I see json formatted data exactly I am looking for but when I save it to some txt file. I see extra quotes added.

### My Code to Save Json to File

```
Dim myFile As String
myFile = "C:\Users\test\Desktop\data.json"
Open myFile For Output As #1
    Write #1, Range("A10").Value  ' Or json (containing data)
Close #1
```

First I convert cells from A1 to F6 into an array of json objects. which is in format:

### right version

```
[
    {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key3": "val3", "key4": "val4"},
    {"key11": "val11", "key12": "val12", "key13": "val13", "key14": "val14"},
    {"key21": "val21", "key22": "val22", "key23": "val23", "key24": "val24"}
]
```

then I save it to data.json file. But I get this in the file.

### wrong version

```
"[
{""key1"":""val1"",""key2"":""val2"",""key3"":""val3"",""key4"":""val4"",""key5"":""val5""}
{""key21"":""val21"",""key22"":""val22"",""key23"":""val23"",""key24"":""val24"",""key25"":""val25""}
]"
```

When I print the **same json data to console (Immediate Window)** in VBA or in **any of the excel cell**, I see the correct version.

I dont understand where am I going wrong?

these is the library I am using, and it gives same result:

Tim Hall - https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON 
I also created my own json converter but I get same result.

Comment: So, does A10 contain the string we see under right version?

Comment: @QHarr yes. A10 contains right version of the string and also when I console log using Debug.Print

Comment: @QHarr only dont know why it adds extra quotes everywhere, when file is saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change write to print

```
Print #1, Range("A10").Value
```

Comment: Is it possible to integrate this to my current code so I dont have to write json first then re-open and save it to remove quotes because i dont prefer this solution.

Comment: You are not understanding the suggestion if you think you need to write json the way you previously did and then re-open it to remove the quotes.  I suggest you try doing exactly what is recommended.

Comment: I will try this and let u know

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, which I got around by doing the following:

```
Open myFile For Input As #1
NewData = Input$(LOF(1), #1)
Close #1

NewData = Replace(NewData, """", "!")
NewData = Replace(NewData, "!!", """")
NewData = Replace(NewData, "!", "")

ml.Cells(x,y) = NewData
```

This might not be the best way to do it, but I ended up getting my json to print how I expected, without the additional quotes.